# Angular dirPaginate custom directive - get last page value in my controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pagination

I need to read the value of the lastPage property (which exists in the custom directove below) from inside my controller.

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

```
        function generatePagination() {
            if (paginationService.isRegistered(paginationId)) {
                var page = parseInt(paginationService.getCurrentPage(paginationId)) || 1;
                scope.pages = generatePagesArray(page, paginationService.getCollectionLength(paginationId), paginationService.getItemsPerPage(paginationId), paginationRange);
                scope.pagination.current = page;

                scope.pagination.last = scope.pages[scope.pages.length - 1];

                // ** here is the code I added that I would like to work **
                parent.scope.lastPage = scope.pagination.last;

                if (scope.pagination.last < scope.pagination.current) {
                    scope.setCurrent(scope.pagination.last);
                } else {
                    updateRangeValues();
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the author's function above in the directive.  It has a property called: scope.pagination.last that I would like to access from my controller.  I tried to do add something like this line: 
parent.scope.lastPage = scope.pagination.last;
but that does not work, or I do not know how to inject parent, etc.

Comment: As i see it, you have 2 options on hand: 1. add properties to generatePagination directive that are bounded to outside properties.    2. create a service that holds the relevant data and inject it to the generatePagination and the controller so they could communicate. what you try doing here is not that good practice cause you making your directive dependent in a parent scope which breaks the directive isolation.

Answer (score 0):

As Ori Price points out, this is not a best practice as it will make this directive dependent on the parent scope ... but maybe you already know that and just need a solution - in that case.  $rootScope is what you're looking for.

3 things you need to do:

1.) add it as a dependency to the directive.

`.directive('dirPaginationControls', ['paginationService', 'paginationTemplate','$rootScope', dirPaginationControlsDirective])`

2.) actually pass it into the directive function:

`function dirPaginationControlsDirective(paginationService, paginationTemplate, $rootScope) { ...`

3.) Use it wherever you want in the directive... for you it would look something like this:

```
function generatePagination() {
        if (paginationService.isRegistered(paginationId)) {
            var page =    parseInt(paginationService.getCurrentPage(paginationId)) || 1;
            scope.pages = generatePagesArray(page, paginationService.getCollectionLength(paginationId), paginationService.getItemsPerPage(paginationId), paginationRange);
            scope.pagination.current = page;

            scope.pagination.last = scope.pages[scope.pages.length - 1];


            $rootScope.lastPage = scope.pagination.last;

            if (scope.pagination.last < scope.pagination.current) {
                scope.setCurrent(scope.pagination.last);
            } else {
                updateRangeValues();
            }
        }
    }
```

You may need to do `$rootScope.$parent.lastPage = scope.pagination.last` I can't remember off the top of my head so do a console.log($rootScope) just to look at all of the options you have access to.